# Reactjs code works without error but executes twice

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

Using aws sdk for iot I'm trying to make a thing and create a certificate on aws iot core platform. Below is the entire code I am using to perform the actions.

```
import {
  IoTClient,
  CreateThingCommand,
  CreateKeysAndCertificateCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-iot";

const Demo = () => {
  var config = {
    region: "us-east-1",
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: "XXXXXXX",
      secretAccessKey: "XXXXXXX",
    },
  };
  const client = new IoTClient(config);
  (async () => {
    const thingRequest = new CreateThingCommand({
      thingName: "demo-thing-name-using-sdk",
    });
    const certificateRequest = new CreateKeysAndCertificateCommand({setAsActive : true});
    try {
      const thingCreated = await client.send(thingRequest);
      const cert = await client.send(certificateRequest);
      let thingArn = thingCreated.thingArn;
      console.log(cert);
      console.log(thingCreated);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  })();
  return null;
};
export default Demo;
```

The above code executes and creates a thing and certificates twice in aws iot core console. Please help me with the problem

Comment: where / how are you calling the function? if its in a useEffect it may be caused by multiple renders in react, fix this by adding an empty dependency array. example: ```useEffect(()=>{/*Run code here*/},[])```
This useEffect will only run when the component mounts.

Comment: Thankyou so much @AlvinCHENG

Comment: Please read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html) on how to provide credentials in a client app. It wouldn't be grea if you expose your credentials to AWS to the client

Answer (score 0):

enter your code in `useEffect` to run only once

```
import React, {  useEffect } from 'react';
```

then in your function

```
useEffect(()=>{
  //enter here your code
},[])
```